# Pivot control copy template failed

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

In my UWP application i have a XAML Pivot control. I'm trying to edit the Template by right-click > edit Template > edit a copy but Visual Studio 2015 (or Blend) gave me the following error prompt :

[image]

(In English Copy Template failed).

Do you have any idea and / or solution for resolve this ?

Thanks in advance

Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sometimes happens to me too and is really annoying.

The Windows SDK provides the default styles and resources for every control in the `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\DesignTime\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\UAP\10.0.xxxxx.0\Generic\generic.xaml` file. Open that file and copy the template manually.